# push method not returning new array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am adding an object to an array through javascript push() method. My array is an array of objects. I want to console.log() the new array. But it is giving me the length of new array. I know push() method returns the length of new array but I want to use the new array in my application. How to get it

```
    let sub_sprite = this.state.sub_sprite;
    let updated_sub_subsprite;
    updated_sub_subsprite = sub_sprite.push(this.state.sprite[that.state.sprite_count]);
    console.log(updated_sub_subsprite);

    that.setState({sub_sprite:updated_sub_subsprite}, ()=>{
         console.log(this.state.sub_sprite)
    });
```

Comment: What you console says?

Comment: use `Array.prototype.concat`. see [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Answer (score 1):

Do not use [Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) on an array stored in your React component's state, it will mutate the state directly, which may lead to problems ([see this article](https://daveceddia.com/why-not-modify-react-state-directly/)).

You can use [Array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to create a new array with the additional value:

```
let sub_sprite = this.state.sub_sprite
let updated_sub_subsprite;
updated_sub_subsprite = sub_sprite.concat([this.state.sprite[that.state.sprite_count]]);
console.log(updated_sub_subsprite);
that.setState({sub_sprite:updated_sub_subsprite}, ()=> {
    console.log(this.state.sub_sprite)
})
```

A more consise and convenient way is using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (notice the three dots):

```
let sub_sprite = this.state.sub_sprite
let updated_sub_subsprite;
updated_sub_subsprite = [...sub_sprite, this.state.sprite[that.state.sprite_count]);
console.log(updated_sub_subsprite);
that.setState({sub_sprite:updated_sub_subsprite}, ()=> {
    console.log(this.state.sub_sprite)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Array#push` method does not return a new array, but rather [the length of the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Return_value) after the item(s) have been added to that array instance.

It looks like the `Array#concat` method would be a better fit for what you're trying to do, [seeing that offers the "appending behavior"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat#Return_value) and also returns the resulting array.

Consider making the following adjustments to your code, making use of `concat()` to achieve what you want:

```
let sub_sprite = this.state.sub_sprite;

// Create a new array via concat(), adding a new array with one item 
// that is [ sub_sprite [that.state.sprite_count] ] to sub_sprite
let updated_sub_subsprite = sub_sprite.concat( [ sub_sprite [that.state.sprite_count] ]);

console.log(updated_sub_subsprite);

that.setState({sub_sprite : updated_sub_subsprite }, ()=>{
    console.log(this.state.sub_sprite)
})
```